# Why can a logged in root account modify this file, but I can't when using sudo

Tags: linux, debian, file-permissions

I have a file on my Debian Stretch server that has the following security attribute: `-rw-r--r--`, owned by root.

If I login as root directly (`su -`), I can edit and save it. But if I try to do `sudo nano filename` to open it with my *admin* user login, when I try to save it it gives me a permission denied error (and wants me to save it as a new file, instead of overwriting the current one).

Why would this be?

Comment: is your user allowed to execute `sudo nano` on the server?

Comment: @Alex yes. Updating question to be a bit more clear.

Comment: Where is the file located?  Is it on a local filesystem or maybe on nfs/fuse fs?

Comment: @Zoredache it's on EC2 - local on the EBS volume

Comment: Does it work if you rename the file or use a different editor?  I'm wondering if this has something to do with nano trying to create a temporary file or loading different profile settings.